# How do I create a zero-one matrix out of all possible paths from source to destination node?

Tags: matlab, matrix, path, undirected-graph

Suppose I have network with 4 nodes and 4 edges as shown below[image]

All possible paths from source node **1** to destination node **4** are

> {{A,C}, {A,B,D}}

From these possible paths, I want to create a zero-one matrix, where number of rows represents the number of paths and number of columns represents the number of edges in a network. The matrix takes **1** as entry if the edge is present in the path to reach destination node, and **0** as its entry if it is not. For above network, path matrix is

> [1 0 1 0; 1 1 0 1]
>    This is because all possible paths are two and hence two rows, and there are 4 edges and hence 4 columns.
>   I have a large complex network with 15 nodes and 107 paths to which I need to apply this technique. Please help.

Comment: How are your paths currently stored?

Comment: @beaker.. As of now, they are stored as a list.

Comment: I don't know what "list" means in terms of Matlab data structures. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @beaker...I found all possible paths from a source node to the destination node. For the above example, I got {{1,2,4},{1,2,3,4}} as possible paths in Woflram Mathematica. But I want to do it in Matlab representing edges and not vertices, and write a path matrix for all possible paths.